# How to bind 8 digit Hex color in angular

Tags: angular, colors, angular8

I have a hex value of white

> ## FFFFFF with alpha 50% as #FFFFFF80

I want to bind this value in HTML component as

```
[style] or [ngStyle]
```

The resultant hex value will be 8 digit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this using `[style]` and `[ngStyle]`

1. Define color directly in template using `[ngStyle]`

```
<span [ngStyle]="{'background-color': '#FFFFFF80'}">
  Background 1
</span>
```

2. Define properties object in component and assign it to `[ngStyle]` in template

Component

```
backgroundProperties = {
  'background-color': '#FFFFFF80'
};
```

Template

```
<span [ngStyle]="backgroundProperties">
  Background 2
</span>
```

3. Assign color using `[style.background-color]`

Component

```
backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF80';
```

Template

```
<span [style.background-color]="backgroundColor">
  Background 3
</span>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jigoot)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[style.background-color]="background"` where `background` is some property on the component with your hex value.

component.html

```html
<div [style.background-color]="background">
</div>
```

component.ts

```js
export class MyComponent {
  background = '#FFFFFF80';
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b21cvn